# Rails - Devise Installation (Succeds/Works on site but files don't exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, devise, rubygems, installation

I installed devise successfully:

```
@ubuntu:~/boltzman$ rails generate devise User
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20111109080820_devise_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/user_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/users.yml
      insert    app/models/user.rb
       route  devise_for :users
```

But I don't see under app->views a folder called devise or any of the devise files, when I do rails server the site works fine, like if you got to /user/sign_in it works. So I'm wondering is this something new? The files are in a different location?

Rails - 3.1.1 (also tried 3.0.9 same issue)
Ubuntu - 11.10
Devise 1.4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow epic fail - so didn't know all I had to do was:

> rails generate devise:views